# Multiplicar un número por un porcentaje en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT JULM_18 / 1000 * 3% AS D15
FROM #TABLE_AR_3
WHERE TERRITORIAL = 'TOTAL'
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Me podrían indicar la manera correcta de multiplicar un número por un porcentaje.

Comment: recuerda que 3% es 3/100, por lo tanto podrías multiplicar el valor por 0.03

Comment: No existe el concepto de número con porcentaje, multiplica por 3 y divide entre 100

Comment: Prueba a Multiplicar por 0.03 que es lo mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz de cuenta que multiplicas y divides como en el colegio. Por orden de operación:

1. divisiones
2. Multiplicaciones
3. Sumas y restas

Dicho esto el orden sería: ((JULM_18 / 1000) * (3 / 100))

El orden viene determinado por paréntesis de dentro hacia fuera, primero se resolverán las operaciones que se encuentren entre paréntesis y por último el que envuelve ambas operaciones.

1. resultado1 = JULM_18 / 1000
2. resultado2 = 3 / 1000
3. resultadoFinal = resultado1 * resultado2

Recuerda que cualquier número divido entre 100 ya representa un porcentaje de algo.

3% de 1000
3/100 = 0.03
0.03 * 1000 = 30

Answer (score 2):

El average en SQL se maneja de la siguiente manera:

ValorSumatoria / 100 = %Porciento

Quiere decir que tu consulta debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT JULM_18 / 1000 * 3 / 100 AS D15
FROM #TABLE_AR_3
WHERE TERRITORIAL = 'TOTAL'
```

Te recomiendo encerrar la primera fracción entre parentesis para mejor entendimiento

```
SELECT (JULM_18 / 1000) * 3 / 100 AS D15
    FROM #TABLE_AR_3
    WHERE TERRITORIAL = 'TOTAL'
```

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que quieras usar `%` trata de dividirlo por `100`
como es tu caso `3 / 100 = 0.03`
 `3% = 0.03`

Prueba esto :

```
SELECT (JULM_18 / 1000) * 0.03 AS D15
FROM #TABLE_AR_3
WHERE TERRITORIAL = 'TOTAL'
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!